# Ubercart - hook for modifying the order review page

Tags: ubercart

What's the ubercart hook for modifying the table when visiting: /?q=user/%/order/%

I'm looking to remove columns in the orders node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documentation is lacking. This is the only documentation i could find and it's here: http://www.ubercart.org/docs/api

but not exactly what i want.